# Active Record Delete is not working properly

Tags: php

I written a simple function to delete  data from the database but the delete query is not properly 
my code for the model is as follows:

```
function removedata()
{
    $userid = $this->input->post('userid');
    $this->db->where('userid', $userid);
    $deldata = $this->db->delete('userbasic');
    if ($deldata == true) {
        echo "Data Removed Successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Deletion Failed";
    }
}
```

I have loaded the database already and tried  both the query i.e.

```
 $this->db->where('userid',$userid);
  $deldata=$this->db->delete('userbasic');
```

and

```
$deldata=$this->db->delete('userbasic',array('userid'=>$userid));
```

So please suggest me answer there is no error in result it also prints data removed successfully but still data is not deleting from the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code seems fine. try to debug.

use this to print the query.

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

and then try execute that query in your phpmyadmin. and check weather it deletes your row.

Comment: I tried this but  it is showing me result DELETE FROM `userbasic` WHERE `userid` = 0.... I checked the name of field in database and input field both are correct

Comment: userid = 0, maybe tats d problem try with id > 0